# Get screenshots from browserstack

Tags: java, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, browserstack

I have created a custom reporting tool based on ExpressJS and NodeJS for my selenium tests. I am storing all information about the executed tests in a own database (testrun, testcases, teststeps and so on).

Now, I want to show a screenshot for every test step. The tests will be executed in browserstack and now I want to get the screenshots from the build and integrate them in my custom report. My first idea was to take the screenshots by my own and store them into the database (or file system), but the images are very big and why not use the screenshots from browsertack.

Is it possible to get the screenshots from browserstack and integrate them into every test step in my custom reporting tool? I know, there is a api from browserstack, but I think it's quite difficult to get them and match it to my current logic. 
The best way would be to get the screenshot path from browserstack at the runtime and store it to my database. Is that possible?

Comment: Can you consider sharing your work please? Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but I have a lot of code and I think it's not related or helpful for my question. I have nothing implemented yet for receiving the screenshots from browserstack.

Answer (score 0):

I get the following answer from browserstack:

> Browserstack REST API which will retrieve the 'Raw logs'. These Raw
>   logs needs to be parsed locally to extract the screenshot URLs
>   generated automatically as a part of the session 'Visual logs'. These
>   URLs can then be stored in the local database. REST API: curl -u
>   ":"
>   https://www.browserstack.com/automate/sessions/.json The
>   above API returns the response in JSON format. Depending on the
>   requirement you can use "logs", "video_url", "browser_url" or
>   "public_url" keys. "logs"                :    Link to access session's
>   Raw Logs "video_url"        :    Link to access session's recorded
>   video "browser_url"    :    Only logged in user can access this
>   session link "public_url"        :    Session link accessible publicly

So, I guess it's not possible to receive the corresponding screenshot at runtime. At the moment, I am using a TestNGListener class to log each test step and store it directly into a db. My idea was to get the screenshot from browserstack, for example when afterNavigateTo is called. But this seems to be impossible. At the moment, I think I have to show my generated log and the visual log from browserstack in a separate view. Or do anyone has an other idea?

Comment: Ok, if you cant get it from the REST API what about:
Taking a screenshot and save it in a (seperated) s3 bucket and not on your server - and then you embed the IMG-URL from your s3 bucket.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code snippet. It worked for me and I got it from http://learn-automation.com/how-to-capture-screenshot-in-selenium-webdriver/

```
import java.io.File;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;

import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class ScreenshootGoogle {

 @Test
 public void TestJavaS1()
{
// Open Firefox
 WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();

// Maximize the window
driver.manage().window().maximize();

// Pass the url
driver.get("http://www.google.com");

// Take screenshot and store as a file format
File src= ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
try {
 // now copy the  screenshot to desired location using copyFile //method
FileUtils.copyFile(src, new File("C:/selenium/error.png"));
}

catch (IOException e)
 {
  System.out.println(e.getMessage());

 }
 }
```